# PHP: Duplicates in creating a select box, need highest valued INTs only

Tags: php, zend-framework, code-duplication

I'm having a bit of an issue with duplication here,
I believe I can clip dupes at any point as long as my return value for 
the dupe remains the the largest int value.

Here's a code stamp:

```
    $unitList = Base_Client_Model::getBusinessUnitList(false, $selectedMarket, false, true);
    $marketListBox = $marketOptions = '';
    $marketList = array();

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $unitList['NUMBER_OF_BUSINESS_UNITS']; $x++) {
    $unitStr = 'BUSINESS_UNIT_' . $x . '_';

        $businessUnit = Base_Client_Model::getBusinessUnit($unitList[$unitStr . 'ID']);
        if ($unitList[$unitStr . 'ID'] && $unitList[$unitStr . 'ID'] != 42) {
            $marketListBox = "<option value='" . $unitList[$unitStr . 'ID'] . "'";
            if($selectedMarket == $unitList[$unitStr . 'ID']) {
                $marketListBox .= ' selected';
                $selectedMarket = 0;
            }

            $marketListBox .= ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . preg_replace('/-Wimax/i', '', $unitList[$unitStr . 'NAME']) . "</option>\n";
            $marketList[$businessUnit->getElement('STATE')][] = $marketListBox;
        }
    }

    ksort($marketList);
    foreach($marketList as $key => $val) {
        $marketOptions .= "<option disabled='disabled'>&nbsp;</option><option disabled='disabled'>{$key}&#172;</option>\n" . implode($val);
    }

    $this->view->marketOptions = $marketOptions;
```

Here's a sample return:

```
<option disabled="disabled">&nbsp;</option><option disabled="disabled">WA¬</option>
<option value="56">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aberdeen</option>
<option value="82">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bellingham</option>
<option value="106">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Everett</option>
<option value="109">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kitsap County</option>
<option value="102">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Seattle</option>
<option value="105">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tacoma</option>
<option value="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tri-Cities</option>
<option value="173">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tri-Cities</option>
<option value="64">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wenatchee</option>
<option value="65">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yakima</option>
<option value="162">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yakima</option>
```

Here is the EXPECTED output:

```
<option disabled="disabled">&nbsp;</option><option disabled="disabled">WA¬</option>
<option value="56">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aberdeen</option>
<option value="82">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bellingham</option>
<option value="106">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Everett</option>
<option value="109">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kitsap County</option>
<option value="102">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Seattle</option>
<option value="105">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tacoma</option>
<option value="173">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tri-Cities</option>
<option value="64">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wenatchee</option>
<option value="162">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yakima</option>
```

I believe the answer is something similar to this

`$unitList['BUSINESS_UNIT_' . $x . '_NAME'] != $unitList['BUSINESS_UNIT_' . $x + 1 . '_NAME']`

Comment: from the code, I think you are using some kind of DB to get this stuff? if yes then why dont you group by max for this and then wrap this guys so you dont need any processing on model or controller layer you can do it in the database layer itself? what do you think about that/

Comment: This is scrapped from an RCAPI request, what you mentioned above won't work, but I believe I found out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a comparison form Wimax and non Wimax markets, where Wimax takes priority

```
            if ($unitList['BUSINESS_UNIT_' . $x . '_NAME'] .'-Wimax' != $unitList['BUSINESS_UNIT_' . ($x + 1) . '_NAME']) {
                $marketListBox = "<option value='" . $unitList[$unitStr . 'ID'] . "'";
                if($selectedMarket == $unitList[$unitStr . 'ID']) {
                    $marketListBox .= ' selected';
                    $selectedMarket = 0;
                }

                $marketListBox .= ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . preg_replace('/-Wimax/i', '', $unitList[$unitStr . 'NAME']) . "</option>\n";
                $marketListArray[$businessUnit->getElement('STATE')][] = $marketListBox;
            }
```